# Oracle Expression Filter has been deprecated and it's not longer supported

Tags: oracle

I noticed that in Oracle 11g there was a file under `rdbms/admin` directory called `catexf.sql`. If it were executed it installed `Expression Filter` feature, but since I moved to Oracle 19c this file isn't longer available there, so it cannot be installed. I checked that this feature and `Rules Manager` are not longer supported. I know that there is a `.jar` file that was prepared for those people that need to upgrade from Oracle 11g to Oracle 19c. But what about those that are installing Oracle 19c as clean installation without any previous oracle, but still need this features to be enabled. Does oracle provided some replacement for that, or these features are already built-in features in Oracle 19c.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a Support contract and so can't read *Support note 1244535.1 Rules Manager and Expression Filter Features of Oracle Database*?

Comment: @APC I do, but I couldn't find this note that you already attached, thank you. Do you know, if missing of these components may impact the "IMP" used to import data pump? I've altered the system user with the password and I am able to connect to this user, but when trying to execute the command I am getting an error that the username/password is invalid, other words `IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1017 encountered`.